# Does XC8 have a particular way to set or clear GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio, xc8

I'm using MPLAB X and XC8 to compile a simple project for the PIC16F886. To manipulate the GPIOs, what I'm doing is

```
#define gpio_ra1(b) (b ? porta |= 0x02 : (porta &= ~(0x02)))
```

and then letting the compiler do its constant propagation and whatever so that the expressions `gpio_ra1(true)` and `gpio_ra1(false)` can be compiled to a single `bcf` or `bsf` instruction. Works great on SDCC, but, at least in the case where `b` evaluates to false, such as in the statement `gpio_ra1(0)`, XC8 produces the following buffoonery:

```
movlw 253                          ; the relevant bit is now 0
movwf ??random_local_variable      ; why is the compiler keeping a copy of this?
movf  ??random_local_variable,w    ; why is the compiler reloading the value it just saved?
bcf 3,5                            ; banksel the gpio ports
andwf 6,f                          ; now bring the gpio pin low
```

I'm not sure what the XC8 compiler is doing with `random_local_variable`; this variable is never used outside of sequences like this, meaning it's never meaningful to read this variable. But my biggest concerns with the generated code are basically

- is the write actually atomic? When I use this on port B it interferes with the in-circuit debugger
- the whole sequence of instructions can just be replaced with `bcf 6,1`.
- does XC8 actually provide an intrinsic you're "supposed to" use?

Comment: Please show the full (but minimal) code producing this assembly, not only the macro definition.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is it better now?

Comment: Not really, as you haven't posted the code. Anyway, the conditional operator (AKA the "ternary") is "designed" to return the evaluated value. In your case you could do something like `x=gpio_ra1(true)` - and then the expectation would be that `x` will receive the value of the evaluated expression (that is `porta |= 0x02`). For that reason the compiler wants to "keep" this value. And looks like it is not optimizing well enough to understand you don't need this value. I suggest to replace the macro with `static inline void` function (with `if/else` construct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of XC8 do you have? Free one or paid? Free one is know to have optimization level limits which cause such useless instructions inserted.

Intrinsic are basically `RA1` macro from `pic16f886.h` (include it). You can browse it for other macros there. Or check out the [XC8 manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/50002053g.pdf), section 5.12.3.2 ACCESSING REGISTERS FROM ASSEMBLY CODE.

Comment: I have the free version of XC8. It's lousy enough I don't want to pay money for it. Where can I find the definition of the `RA1` macro?

Comment: I've already wrote where you can find it. What do you mean?

Comment: Oh, I understand now.